# HTTP Status 500. servlet

Tags: java, tomcat

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]всем привет, сделал я servlet для tomcat, захожу на сайт а он мне ошибку:

HTTP Status 500 - index (wrong name: web/index)

type Exception report

message index (wrong name: web/index)

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: index (wrong name: web/index)

что делать ?

Вот код servlet:

```
package web;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
public class Index extends HttpServlet {
     @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)     throws ServletException, IOException {
   res.setContentType("text/html");
   PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
   out.println("<html>");
   out.println("<head>");
   out.println("<title>asd</title");
   out.println("</head>");
   out.println("</html>");
   }

 }
```

web.xml:

```
 <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5">
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>web/Index</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/index</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `<servlet-class>web.index</servlet-class>`

Comment: @СергейГорностаев , спавибо за быстрый ответ у меня теперь журагая ошибка HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class web.index

Comment: `web.Index` а не `web/Index`

Comment: @Сергей Горностаев не чего не поменялось, ошибка таже

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас декларируется все одновременно и аннотациями, и в web.xml. 
Вы должны использовать что-то одно.

В index нужно указать полное имя класса. У вас это, видимо, web.index

И названия классов пишутся с заглавной буквы.

Comment: я поменял название класс и дописал web <servlet-class>web.Index</servlet-class>. я убрал из кода  @Override
у меня теперь другая ошибка javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class web.Index

Comment: Оставьте @Override и уберите @WebServlet("/s");

Comment: та же ошибка java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: web/Index javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class web/Index

Comment: Обновите вопрос: напишите актуальный код сервлета, web.xml, добаьвте полный вывод стектрейса и структуру вашего проекта.

Comment: обновил, и всё написал

Comment: всё заработало !

Comment: я создал папку web и туда положил class index. web.xml web.Index